# Browserify модульная подгрузка

Tags: javascript

Как настроить browserify так, чтобы он при сборке не дублировал скрипты.

Пример: На странице подключаются два скрипта, один это основной bundle.js (точка входа в приложение), второй, module.js, может подрубиться в любой момент (динамически... когда возникнет необходимость). Оба файла используют одну библиотеку, допустим jquery. Как сделать чтобы module.js не содержал в себе всю библиотеку jquery? т.к. она уже есть в bundle.js.

**index.html**

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script src="module.js"></script>
```

**bundle.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

**module.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

**UPD**

[gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Crysp/e35f5a9f6b3e7c7a748c#file-bundle-js-L57) - bundle.js который у меня получается. Видно jquery забиндин

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете, например, вообще вынести jQuery за пределы сборок, и в ручную подключать jQuery к странице. Такой подход оказывается очень полезным, когда кроме собственного кода, нужно использовать какие-то сторонние jQuery плагины, которые не совместимы с *CommonJS*.

Для того, чтобы использовать глобальный объект `jQuery` через `require` вам нужно будет использовать плагин [*browserify-shim*](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim). Он конфигурируется через `package.json` и вам нужно будет добавить туда следующие строчки:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:jQuery",
}
```

**index.html** будет иметь вид:

```
<!-- Здесь нужно использовать реальный путь для jQuery -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<!-- А эти сборки не будут содержать jQuery -->
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script src="module.js"></script>
```

Файлы **bundle.js** и **module.js** остануться не изменными.

Comment: у меня стоит жесткое условие, что все глобальные плагины подключаются в bundle.js

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет ни слова об этом ;)

Comment: не знаю... вообщем задача состоит в том чтобы реализовать логику похожую на webpack. т.е. у него есть точка входа ```bundle.js``` и потом при необходимости подгружает нужный кусок ```bundle-[id].js```, при этом код не дублируется

Comment: @ВиталийЛеонов, если вы хотите паковать jQuery только раз, то вам в любом случае придется использовать глобальный контекст. Один из вариантов того, как это можно сделать, я предложил. Может быть кто-то предложит вариант лучше :)